# Can someone explain me how custom hooks get the data and in depth flow of custom hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-custom-hooks

```
//use Input HOOK
```

I want to know that how this custom hook work

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default initialValue => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
  return {
    value,
    onChange: event => {
      setValue(event.target.value);
    },
    reset: () => setValue("")
  };
};


//todo form
```

How this onchange method work how it update the data even though no onchange function is write in this programm

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import useInputState from "./useInputState";

const TodoForm = ({ saveTodo }) => {
  const { value, reset, onChange } = useInputState("");

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        saveTodo(value);
        reset();
      }}
    >
      <TextField
        variant="outlined"
        placeholder="Add todo"
        margin="normal"
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </form>
  );
};

export default TodoForm;
```

[view full programm Code Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-with-materialui-forked-pu05h9?file=/src/TodoForm.js:0-561)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. This hook basically moves some of the standard boilerplate you'd otherwise typically write for form inputs into a single function (the custom hook you quote). It returns some props/attributes, including the `onChange` handler, that you pass to the input. If you have a more specific question, please edit your question to make that clearer.

Comment: _ even though no onchange function is write in this program_ - yes there is! `onChange: event => setValue(event.target.value)`

Answer (score 0):

Functions in JS are treated like any other variable. So the `de-structured onChange` (in the component) is taking the reference for a function which is defined anonymously in the `custom hook`, which is then used by the onChange method of the `TextField` component.
This is similar to how you pass variables by reference is JS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).